How to filter out null values from a Dart list while ensuring type safety?
I'm working with a list in Dart that contains nullable elements. I want to filter out the null values and have a List with non-nullable elements. Here's the code I'm using:
List<int?> t = [1, 2, 3, 4, null, 5];
List<int> tWithOutNulls = t.where((e) => e != null).map((e) => e).toList();

However, this line gives me a type error:
A value of type 'List<int?>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<int>'.

I can fix it by explicitly casting with a non-null assertion:
List<int> tWithOutNulls = t.where((e) => e != null).map((e) => e!).toList();

But I wonder if there’s a more elegant or idiomatic way to achieve this in Dart. For example, in TypeScript, we can use a type guard function like this:
function notEmpty<TValue>(value: TValue | null | undefined): value is TValue {
    return value !== null && value !== undefined;
}

const array: (string | null)[] = ['foo', 'bar', null, 'zoo', null];
const filteredArray: string[] = array.filter(notEmpty);


In your case you can use whereType<T> method:

Creates a new lazy Iterable with all elements that have type T.
The matching elements have the same order in the returned iterable as
they have in iterator.

Like this:
List<int> tWithOutNulls = t.whereType<int>().toList();


Full example

Use either:
List<int> ts = [...t.nonNulls];

or
List<int> ts = t.nonNulls.toList();

or the extra manual way
List<int> ts = [for (var e in t) if (e != null) e];

